# Move center of rotated element to cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I want to move an element with the cursor while kipping the center of the element at the cursor position, I know how to do it but the problem starts when the element is rotated.
Here are the snippets:

Not rotated:

```js
var offset = [0,0];
var el;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     el = document.getElementById("el");

     offset = [
        parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("width"))/2,
        parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("height"))/2
    ];

    document.addEventListener('mousemove',fun,false);
        
});

function fun(event) { 
    mousePosition = {

        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY

    };

    el.style.left = (mousePosition.x - offset[0]) + 'px';
    el.style.top  = (mousePosition.y - offset[1]) + 'px';

  }
```

```css
#el{
  background: red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="el">not rotated works fine</div>
```

Rotated:

```js
var offset = [0,0];
var el;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     el = document.getElementById("el");

     offset = [
        parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("width"))/2,
        parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("height"))/2
    ];

    document.addEventListener('mousemove',fun,false);
        
});

function fun(event) { 
    mousePosition = {

        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY

    };

    el.style.left = (mousePosition.x - offset[0]) + 'px';
    el.style.top  = (mousePosition.y - offset[1]) + 'px';

  }
```

```css
#el{
  background: red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform: rotateZ(-55deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateX(-25deg) ;
}
```

```html
<div id="el">rotated, doesn't work</div>
```

Any idea to do it easily and nicely?
Thanks In Advance.

**Edit:** 
I need the `transform-origin` for animation so changing `transform-origin` to 0 is not enough, I need also to animate the location.
Is there any tool to convert this transformation:

```
transform-origin: 0% 100%;
transform: rotateZ(-55deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateX(-25deg) ;
```

into this pattern :

```
transform-origin: center;
transform: rotateZ() rotateY() rotateX() translateX() translateY() translateZ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the styling as following.

```
#el{
  background: red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform-origin: center;      /* This is changed :) */
  transform: rotateZ(-55deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateX(-25deg) ;
}
```

Comment: So you are saying that  `transform-origin` only affect location?

Comment: Absolutely, I have confirmed your code working with that change on code

Comment: I got confused because I made the snippet without animation , I need this  `transform-origin ` for animation not for location so your solution is not enough i need also a way to calculate the location transformation and do it manually.

Comment: I found the answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin